# Django: ModelFormSet saving first entry only

Tags: django, django-forms, formset

Update:

The issue seemed to be in the coding for Django-formset. I was processing it as an inline formset and not a model formset. The answer below was also correct. Thanks!

I am working with a model formset for an intermediate model. I am using django-formset js to add additional formset fields on the template. Most everything works OK except that when I go to save the formset only the first entry is being saved to the DB. The first entry is saved and assigned correctly but any after than just disappear. It is not throwing any errors so I am not sure what is going wrong. Thanks!

The Model

```
class StaffAssignment(models.Model):
    study = models.ForeignKey(Study, related_name='study_set', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    staff = models.ForeignKey('account.UserProfile', related_name='assigned_to_set', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    assigned_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-role',)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} is assigned to {}'.format(self.staff, self.study)
```

The Form:

```
class AddStaff(forms.ModelForm):
    model = StaffAssignment
    fields = ('staff',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddStaff, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
```

The View:

```
def add_staff(request, study_slug):
    study = get_object_or_404(Study, slug=study_slug)
    staff_formset = modelformset_factory(StaffAssignment, form=AddStaff, fields=('staff',), can_delete=True)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        staffList = staff_formset(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if staffList.is_valid():
            for assignment in staffList:
                assigned = assignment.save(commit=False)
                assigned.study = study
                assigned.role = assigned.staff.job_title
                assigned.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('studies:studydashboard'))
        else:
            HttpResponse('Something is messed up')
    else:
        staffList = staff_formset(queryset=StaffAssignment.objects.none())
        return render(request, 'studies/addstaff.html', {'staffList': staffList, 'study': study})
```

The Template:

```
    <form action="{% url 'studies:addstaff' study.slug %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="box-body">
            {% for list in staffList %}
                <div class="form-group" id="formset">
                {% if list.instance.pk %}{{ list.DELETE }}{% endif %}
                    {{ list.staff }}
                    {% if list.staff.errors %}
                        {% for error in list.staff.errors %}
                            {{ error|escape }}
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            {{ staffList.management_form }}
    </div>
    <div class="box-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not including the primary key field in the template, as [required by the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-the-formset-in-the-template). Add

```
{% for list in staffList %}
    {{ list.pk }}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: So I tried that and I also tried just doing `{{list}}` and letting Django generate the forms but that didn't work either.

Comment: Also if I add `extra=3` to the formset definition is `views.py` then the first 3 entries will be saved.